# grunt-ts and tsc producing different results

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, npm, tsc, grunt-ts

I am using a tsconfig.json file in conjunction with grunt-ts here is the grunt task:

```
ts: {
    default: {
    tsconfig: true
  }
```

and the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

When I try to run this grunt task I get an error TS2300 from duplicate identifiers.  the `exclude: "typings/main"` is meant to avoid this, and it works when running tsc from the command line, but not when running the grunt-ts task. Somewhat confused as it is definitely excluding `node_modules` in the compilation, but not the typings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to run this grunt task I get an error TS2300 from duplicate identifiers. the exclude: "typings/main" is meant to avoid this, and it works when running tsc from the command line, but not when running the grunt-ts task

Verified bug. The issue you created : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/issues/334 is actually a duplicate of https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/issues/285 and up for grabs

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Looks like someone has already submitted a PR to fix it.